# Jboss 6.4 Infinispan 8.2 and JGroups - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jboss, jboss6.x, infinispan, jgroups

I need some features from Infinispan 8+. Therefore I have updated my company app pom.xml with the newest Infinispan pom.

It was quite straightforward, but the app uses jgroups (or its default config in default-configs/default-jgroups-udp.xml - this location is different from previous versions of infinispan). The default versions have some parameters (and the  XSD from Jgroups version 3.6) - so I also bumped jgroups to 3.6.8.Final as it looks like it is the intended version (and the version that does not complain about unknown parameters in default config in infinispan 8.2)

so the pom is the following:

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jgroups</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgroups</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
            <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>                
            <version>8.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Anyway - this application starts with no problems using spring-boot with Jetty. I am pretty sure it would start on any application server.

But then I have no choice but to run it on JBoss 6.4. 
There I got an exception involving some jboss.as classes (this is kind of unexpected) during the deployment:

```
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start() on object of type JGroupsTransport
    at org.infinispan.commons.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:172)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$PrioritizedMethod.invoke(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:859)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeStartMethods(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:628)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:617)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:542)
    at org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry.start(GlobalComponentRegistry.java:234)
    ... 141 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.jgroups.conf.XmlConfigurator.<clinit>(XmlConfigurator.java:35)
    at org.jgroups.conf.ConfiguratorFactory.getStackConfigurator(ConfiguratorFactory.java:62)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.<init>(JChannel.java:129)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.buildChannel(JGroupsTransport.java:419)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.initChannel(JGroupsTransport.java:320)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.initChannelAndRPCDispatcher(JGroupsTransport.java:366)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start(JGroupsTransport.java:190)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.infinispan.commons.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:168)
    ... 146 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups.LogFactory from [Module "deployment.mymodule-5.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.appName.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jgroups.logging.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:31)
    ... 158 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups.LogFactory from [Module "deployment.mymodule-5.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.appName.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.jgroups.logging.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:28)
    ... 158 more
```

My guess is that **org.jgroups.logging.LogFactory** somehow discovers that is is running on a Jboss and tries to use **org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups.LogFactory** but this version of Jboss does not have one. (the server directory **EAP-6.4.0\modules\system\layers\base\org\jgroups\main** contains jgroups version 3.2.X).

Is there any walkaround to use this jgroups version (and so Infinispan 8.2) in Jboss 6.4?

This is (the application) an ear file so I can manipulate jboss-deployment-structure.xml file, but so far I only came with excluding Jboss original jgroups, and this did not help.

```
 <exclusions>
        <module name="org.jgroups"/>
 </exclusions>
```

Comment: JGroups follows the property `jgroups.logging.log_factory_class` - could you set that to `org.jgroups.logging.Log4J2LogImpl`? (this disables integration into EAP logging and logs to whatver log4j2 impl there is, but it would be a starting point...)

Comment: In fact the problem seems to be that the property is set withing server for EAP-internal version of JGroups, but it's grabbed by your application version of JGroups. Then, the app JGroups try to load the EAP-JGroups integration class which is not on its classpath. So, you could also add `org.jgroups.extension` module as dependency, but no guarantees here.

Comment: @Flavius
Ok I was able to change the property to Log4J2LogImpl, but (we are using SL4J) I got
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.Level. We are using log4j-over-slf4j so this should be available. I printed out (in code) the Jar that loads the class (Level) - it turned out is is EAP-6.4.0/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/log4j/logmanager/main/log4j-jboss-logmanager-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar . Excluding module org.jboss.log4j.logmanager does not change it.

Comment: @Flavius
I decided to create my own LogFactory for Jgroups (found it by reading javadoc for Log4J2LogImpl http://www.jgroups.org/javadoc/org/jgroups/logging/package-summary.html). Looks like this helped, when I put the created class under jgroups.logging.log_factory_class system property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently bug with Infinispan 8 + EAP 6.4 combination. The reason is exactly as @Flavius says in comments. Currently there is discussion where to fix it, but it'll mostly likely be fixed in EAP 6.4. I'm sure it will be done soon.

I can only offer you a working workarounds.

1. Use WildFly - the issue is not present there anymore
2. Little nasty workaround, but it works:

   1. Call `System.clearProperty("jgroups.logging.log_factory_class");` in the deployment
   2. Include JBoss Logging of version specified in infinispan-bom in your deployment (e.g. add jboss-logging Maven dependency in your pom.xml)
   3. Provide `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` to your deployment, which excludes the server's JBoss logging, see below:

```
    <jboss-deployment-structure>
        <deployment>
            <exclusions>
                <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
            </exclusions>
        </deployment>
    </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand, that I should just choose one of the given points, not do all at once? :)

Comment: Either use WildFly or perform those three steps under "Little nasty workaround, but it works" :)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility if none of the above workarounds work (for instance the app uses other log mechanisms) is to implement an own 
http://www.jgroups.org/javadoc/org/jgroups/logging/CustomLogFactory.html

The log factory must return a log instance, implementing it for any other logger is straightforward with methods trace/error/debug etc.

Then this logger class can be set with `System.setProperty("jgroups.logging.log_factory_class","my.company.logging.MyJgroupsLog");`